# Compiling sqlite Levenshtein function for System.Data.SQLite

Tags: sqlite, compilation, system.data.sqlite

OK, I'm new to compiling programs, and I have literally tried everything.

I downloaded System.Data.SQLite from here:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

This allowed me to get sqlite functionality into my C# application. Now I'm looking to add a Levenshtein function so that I can do a search to find similar results in my c# application.

I stumbled upon:
https://github.com/mateusza/SQLite-Levenshtein

But I honestly have no clue how to compile it and load it as an extension. I read about the sqlite extensions on sqlite's main website.

I have an idea about how to load my extension: Run select load_extension('path to .dll'), but I don't know how to turn that SQLite-Levenshtein into a dll file that can be loaded from sqlite. I would appreciate any help you can give. (Please bear with me, I'm slowly diving into wide world of compiling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I compiled this extension with mingw GCC:

```
gcc -s -O4 -I /path/to/sqlite/headers/ -shared -o levenshtein.dll levenshtein.c
```

`/path/to/sqlite/headers/` is the place where `sqlite3ext.h` file is located.

If your platform is x86 (32-bit), you may take http://www.siftsoft.com/misc/levenshtein.dll -- that's what I built from git HEAD right now.